# How to parse xml with duplicate children in jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

As per the below sample xml we need to parse the text in same order. I am using find() method to get the value of node but all the paragraphs are combining together and all the multimedia combining together.

How to get expected output like below
**Any help would be appreciated**

```
        <section ID="warn">
           <title>WARNINGS</title>
           <text>
              <paragraph>first sample text</paragraph>
              <multimedia>sample Media1</multimedia>
              <paragraph>Second sample text</paragraph>
              <paragraph>Third sample text</paragraph>
              <paragraph>Fourth sample text</paragraph>
              <multimedia>sample Media2</multimedia>
              <paragraph>Fifth sample text</paragraph>
           </text>

     </component>

Expected output should be like below

WARNINGS
first sample text
sample Media1
Second sample text
Third sample text
Fourth sample text
sample Media2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
var nodes = $("section *").filter(function() {
  return $(this).children().length == 0;
});

nodes.each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5956/)

- Filter out the end nodes, which don't have child elements.
- Then loop through them to get the text inside it.